# My url doesn't work with / in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

In Codeigniter URL , I remove index.php 
in Config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

url: http://localhost/code/test **it's work** 
But this url : http://localhost/code/test/  **doesn't work!**
And this : http://localhost/code/test/name **doesn't work!**

Comment: You have set your URI protocol to `REQUEST_URI`, but you are passing to `QUERY_STRING`. Change the last line to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` or `RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]`.

Comment: it's doesn't load images in page.

Comment: Do not delete the two `RewriteCond` lines, and make sure your image `src` starts with `/`.

Comment: @AmirHossein show me your base URL

Comment: What version of CI you using

Comment: My images sorce is ok in this url : http://localhost/code/test , but in this controller , i have new function called test, images not work!

Comment: @Abdulla $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/code/';

Comment: @wolfgang1983 2.2.6

Comment: Try with `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` not CI3 versions does not have AUTO only CI2

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i try AUTO , not working ! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Check if your .htaccess is in your root directory.

Step 2: replace the code in the .htaccess with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

No need of the IfModule tags

Step 3: Go to application->config->config.php, find and replace these ones,

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Step 4: Restart your server.

Comment: my index.php is remove , That's ok, but in my controller "test" , i have new Function called "name" , images not work in this controller!

Comment: if i have / in end of url , like this: http://localhost/code/test/ , doesn't work !!

Comment: Are you sure, that if you put / in the end of url it doesnt work, even when you restarted the server? what is the version of CI you are using? and also are you using XAMPP,?

Comment: Yes i using XAMPP , Version CI : 2.2.6 , Page is load , but images not load ! ( also style and javascript is loaded ) images not load in this page, with / or new function in controller

Comment: for the image part, try like this and see..
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|[image root folder name]|robots\.txt)

Comment: try this too! not working! and also why loaclhost/code/events/ not load images and navigation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113248/discussion-between-arulpragash-and-amir-hossein).

Answer (score 1):

Use this `.htaccess`

```
# -FrontPage-

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in `application/config/conifg.php` add these

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: everything in "test" Controller is Ok, but in this url: localhost/code/test/ not work ! images and javascript dosen't work! and also if i have new function , not working

Comment: @AmirHossein  try `localhost/index.php/code/test/` and see

Answer (score 1):

change as below

in config.php

$config['base_url'] = '/appname/';
$config['index_page'] = '';

in .htaccess

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appname/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This should work